# USB malfunction preventing system shutdown and My Computer page fails to load

Tags: windows-xp, usb-flash-drive, virus

I own a Lenovo G530 which is running Window XP Service Pack 3. I have run into some problem which concerns the USB ports. Yesterday, I inserted a USB flash drive (pen drive) into one of the port. Since then, the `My Computer` page fails to load. A flash light icon appears and keeps searching for drivers and folders forever. `The drivers themselves are accessible through the command prompt or through the Run interface.`

After this problem occurred, I tried to shut-down the system but it hung on `Saving Your Settings`. I did force shutdown through the power button. After re-starting the system, the problem persists. My Computer view is stuck in the scan phase. Also, I am unable to use my USB internet data card.

How can make my computer functional again? Please advice.

EDIT:

One of the event log errors:

```
The device 'JMB38X SD/MMC Host Controller' 
(PCI\VEN_197B&DEV_2382&SUBSYS_3D9B17AA&REV_00\4&1a9c2d41&0&00E0)
disappeared from the system without first being prepared for removal.
```

Comment: If you remove this device does your computer function correctly?  **If that is the case then the device is broken.**  If this problems happens on every port then the device is broken.

Comment: @Ramhound No, I have removed the USB pen drive all together, but still the `My Computer` and shutdown issue persists.

Comment: Does the problem exist in `Safe Mode`?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet... I will an inform you accordingly. Thx

Comment: @Ramhound My system seems to be working fine while in Safe Mode. But I found a lot of irregularities with the way the OS is loading.

Comment: @Ramhound The task manager is not running all the processes it used to. Some 30 odd processes are running. The task manager shows 2 instance of explorer.exe running. Also, the event viewers show multiple error messages and most of them are about failing to load drivers. I have updated one such event.

Comment: I have no idea if `/sfc scannow` exits on Windows XP but have you tried that?  The fact its working in `Safe Mode` indicates a driver problem.  This means even using a system restore point or the best solution at this pointing creating a fresh system image.